# Should I Use ExceptionFilter or Middleware for Exception Handling in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, filter, middleware

I am using .NET 5 and I need to global exception handling mechanism.

Should I use [ExceptionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.exceptionfilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or Middleware? Which one is the best practice for most of the ASP.NET Core applications?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on ExceptionFilter, but I would suggest a best practice would be to use middleware as part of your http pipeline - e.g. enrich a message.. ie part of a happy path. I don't think a middleware can catch exceptions The ExceptionFilter would seem to catch exceptions thrown by a controller action.

Answer (score 2):

As general guidance, you should pick the middleware over the filter whenever is possible.

If you don't need any specific constructs from MVC, then you can safely implement your thing by using middleware. If you want to use MVC constructs (eg: `ModelState` or `IActionResults`), then use a filter because it will enable access to MVC.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you just want to handle the MVC or web api related exception, you could choose both ExceptionFilter and UseExceptionHandler(middelware).

If you want to handle the exception which is outside the MVC and inside the middelware.

I suggest you could try to use [UseExceptionHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) middleware to help you.

Notice: For some specific logic like that if the exception occurred when the call was made to POST /orders then you want to log a different exception and if it was in another action then do something else. In such a case use a Filter.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6/7, I think exception filters are the way to go.
Writing an exception filter like this

```cs
public class ErrorHandlingFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        ProblemDetails problemDetails = new()
        {
            Title = "An error occurred while processing your request.",
            Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
        };

        context.Result = new ObjectResult(problemDetails);

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

will also return the correct Content-Type of **application/problem+json** per
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807.txt

```js
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 08 Nov 2022 22:52:13 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "title": "An error occurred while processing your request.",
  "status": 500
}
```

The best solution is to UseExceptionHandler
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#exception-handler-page

Comment: You think exception filters are the way to go, but the best solution is to use UseExceptionHandler? These contradict...

Comment: If the choice is between the exception filter and middleware, go with the exception filter.